# No me funciona el click en List View

Tags: android, listview, click

Buenas compañeros, no consigo que el click sobre algún item del ListView me funcione. Tengo puesto un Toast y cuando pulsó se cae la aplicación.

Este es mi método.

```
public class BusquedaPartidos extends AppCompatActivity implements CargarJSON.Listener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private ListView lvConsulta;
private Button btnConsultaTodos;
private EditText edConsulta;
private Button btnVolverBuscar;

public static final String URLConsultaTodos = "http://appjerez.es/futpad/consultaTodos.php"; //http://proyecto2gs.esy.es/consultaTodos.php";//"http://proyecto2gs.esy.es/consultaTodos.php";
private List<HashMap<String, String>> mAndroidMapList = new ArrayList<>();

private static final String KEY_DEPORTE = "deporte";
private static final String KEY_NIVEL = "nivel";
private static final String KEY_NUMJUG = "numjug";
private static final String KEY_POLIDEPORTIVO = "polideportivo";
private static final String KEY_FECHAPAR = "fechapar";
private static final String KEY_HORAPAR = "horapar";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buscar_partidos);

    edConsulta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edConsulta);
    lvConsulta = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvConsulta);

    btnVolverBuscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVolverBuscar);
    btnVolverBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent btnLoge = new Intent(BusquedaPartidos.this, BusquedaPartidos.class);
            startActivity(btnLoge);
        }
    });
    btnConsultaTodos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConsultaTodos);
    btnConsultaTodos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (edConsulta.getText().toString().equals("Todos")) {
                loadListView();
            }else if (edConsulta.getText().toString().equals("Padel")){
                ConsultaPadel();
            }else if (edConsulta.getText().toString().equals("Futbol")) {
                ConsultaFutbol();
            }
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onLoaded(List<AdaptadorListview> androidList) {

    for (AdaptadorListview android : androidList) {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put(KEY_DEPORTE, android.getDeporte());
        map.put(KEY_NIVEL, android.getNivel());
        map.put(KEY_POLIDEPORTIVO, android.getPolideportivo());
        map.put(KEY_FECHAPAR, android.getFechapar());
        map.put(KEY_HORAPAR, android.getHorapar());

        mAndroidMapList.add(map);
    }
}

@Override
public void onError() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Error !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    Toast.makeText(this, mAndroidMapList.get(i).get(KEY_DEPORTE),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private void loadListView() {

    new CargarJSON(this).execute(URLConsultaTodos);
    ListAdapter todos = new SimpleAdapter(BusquedaPartidos.this, mAndroidMapList, R.layout.item_listview_consultas,
            new String[] { KEY_DEPORTE, KEY_NIVEL, /*KEY_NUMJUG,*/ KEY_POLIDEPORTIVO, KEY_FECHAPAR, KEY_HORAPAR },
            new int[] { R.id.deporte, R.id.nivel,/* R.id.numjug,*/ R.id.polideportivo, R.id.fechapar, R.id.horapar });

    lvConsulta.setAdapter(todos);

}
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué mensaje muestra el log ?

Comment: 06-12 18:48:17.958 3360-3360/com.example.javier.proyectofutpad E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
06-12 18:48:17.959 3360-3360/com.example.javier.proyectofutpad E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
06-12 18:48:17.959 3360-3360/com.example.javier.proyectofutpad E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive

Comment: puede poner un poco mas de codigo? como la clase en la que esta el listview

Comment: Si claro, te pongo todo el codigo.

Comment: He editado la pregunta, ahora esta todo el código. Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Prueba después de agregar los elementos a la lista, llama al método `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Aun no he podido probarlo  personalmente, pero por lo he visto ahora por encima, veo que implementas el metodo de ListView onItemclick pero no se lo asignas al listview que estas usando. En el onCreate solo estas asignandole el view con el findViewbyID, pero despues tienes que asginarle el metodo onitemclick que has implementado. Despues lo probare y te comento.

Comment: Gracias, pero ya me funciona el toast del click. me ayudarias mucho si me dices como se

Comment: Ahora necesito que cada item del list view tenga un intent diferente... no consigo hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Pon un try catch que encierre el Toast en el que crees que te da el error y escribe que mensaje te da la excepción, así podremos ayudarte mejor, puede ser el contexto que usas o que de error al intentar obtener el objeto

```
mAndroidMapList.get(i).get(KEY_DEPORTE)
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono el Toast.

Comment: Podrias decirme como hago para que indicar un intent a cada item del listview

Comment: Lo importante es que cuando hagas click en un elemento lo recuperes completamente, así puedes cargar el intent con los datos del elemento recuperado. Yo lo recojo así: TipoObjeto value = (TipoObjeto)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); (Esto se pone donde muestras el Toast) Ahora, teniendo el objeto con todas sus propiedades puedes rellenar el intent como quieras o incluso mediante if o switch puedes crear intent diferentes dependiendo de alguna propiedad del objeto recuperado.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer en el onCreate te falto crear el manejador del listView:

lvConsulta.setOnItemClickListener(this);

Saludos